# Is there a way to use the GPIO pins as a button?

Tags: gpio

Im currently setting up picroft on my Raspberry and once i have it running, i would like to create a command, which basically emulates a button press. Im planning on controlling my lights with it but due to my lights my only option is to pry open the remote for the lights and "bypass"/replace the button with the Raspberrys gpio pins. Now i realised that i cant just short two pins via code(atleast i think i cant) so i need a way to press a button/short a connection via the gpio pins. I thought about using a NPN-Transistor, but i also don't know if that will work, since thats not realy a button(I mean kind of, but not what i'm looking for). Any hints or solutions appreciated. Best Wishes

Comment: I'd look at either copying the remote codes (is it infra red or RF ?) or see if someone else has already interfaced with your lights. Which ones are they ?

Comment: How powerful are your lights? If they are basic LEDs, then you can wire them up to your pi or better yet, make a hat.  If they are mains voltage, they should be controlled using a relay. There are many existing hats that will work for this.

Comment: @NomadMaker The OP is talking about hacking the remote, ie., has no intention of attaching the lights to the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the circuit on the other end detects the button press and you have a common ground between that circuit and your pi, you might be able to fake a button press directly with a gpio pin and maybe a pull up / pull down resistor.  However, this is messy (and possibly dangerous).

A safer solution is to use a relay, solid state relay, or in special circumstances, an opto-isolator switch, and have the pi gpio pin drive it.

If you look through the robotics hats, there are multiple solutions that use these methods.

However (as suggested in comments), it might be easier to record the output from your IR remote and replay it using a special IR remote LED connected directly to a GPIO pin.  They sell both special IR receivers and IR emitters for exactly this purpose (both look like a normal LED but are not), as the IR signal from the remote is typically at a specific IR frequency with an underlying modulation to reduce noise.